# When is it better to use value comparison instead of identify comparison when checking if a string is unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, comparison-operators

The origin of this question is the flask tutorial at http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask.  While reading this tutorial, I came across this function:

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods = ['PUT'])
def update_task(task_id):
    task = filter(lambda t: t['id'] == task_id, tasks)
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    if 'title' in request.json and type(request.json['title']) != unicode:
        abort(400)
    if 'description' in request.json and type(request.json['description']) is not unicode:
        abort(400)
    if 'done' in request.json and type(request.json['done']) is not bool:
        abort(400)
    task[0]['title'] = request.json.get('title', task[0]['title'])
    task[0]['description'] = request.json.get('description', task[0]['description'])
    task[0]['done'] = request.json.get('done', task[0]['done'])
    return jsonify( { 'task': task[0] } )
```

This line uses value comparison:

```
if 'title' in request.json and type(request.json['title']) != unicode:
```

But this line uses identity comparison:

```
if 'description' in request.json and type(request.json['description']) is not unicode:
```

Is there a reason that the author was not consistent?  Will both versions provide the same level of security?  If so, what is the more pythonic approach?

Comment: If you are talking about "!=" and "is not", Value comparison "!=" is deprecated in latest version, so people who are habituated to use "!=" will continue to use sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better use json schema instead:

```
from jsonschema import validate, ValidationError

schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'title': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
        'description': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
        'done': {
            'type': 'boolean',
        },
    },
}

try:
    validate(request.get_json(), schema)
except ValidationError:
    abort(400)
```

Also `request.json` is deprecated if you use `flask>=0.10`, and better use `request.get_json()`: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.json.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer this way:

```
if isinstance(request.json['title'], unicode):
    pass
```

Comment: This is better than either of the two versions in the code example in the question.

Comment: If you will not have `title` key, then you will get `KeyError` exception. I think better `isinstance(request.get_json().get('title'), basestring)`

Comment: isinstance('asdasd', basestring) -> True (I mean not `unicode`)

Answer (score 0):

Will both versions provide the same level of security?
->no

it is not a question of which one is more pythonic,it is a question of which level  you want to compare at. consider this and you will know the answer yourself:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1.0
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
>>> id(a)
12777000
>>> id(b)
14986000
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> a is b
True
>>> a == b
True
>>> id(a)
12777000
>>> id(b)
12777000
```

but note this :

```
>>> a=1000
>>> b=1000
>>> a is b
False

>>> a='good'
>>> b='good'
>>> a is b
True
>>> a='啊'
>>> b='啊'
>>> a is b
False
>>> a==b
True
```

the reason is the notion of buffer pool.
So,when you want to compare **value**,'=' and '!=' is safer

when **id**,'is' and 'is not' is safer(but do note the buffer pool)